# Adding link to the dynamic list of data from table and directed list should display the data

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a page that needs to link with the dynamically created list. here is the code of the list.

```
$str="<td class='name'><a href='display.php?title=".$list["sn"][$i]."'>".$list["title"][$i]."</a>";
```

and in in display.php i need to get the title's that is created in above list and match that title with the name of the table for that i have one table named "list" with fields (1) sn (2) title (3) project_id and another table named  "listmap" with fields (1) sn (2) project_id (3)table_name. so the listmap table will map the respective table name of the individual listed title of the project.
e. g in the "list" table data are as follows
sn==1, title==Water project project_id==1 
 in list "listmap" table, sn==1 project_id==1 and table_name==waterp

and i have individual table for each item as in above like "waterp"

i have tried to make it possible with some query as follows

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM listmap where project_id = $_GET['title'];
") or die(mysql_error());
$query1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM { $data['table_name']}") ;   
$result=mysql_fetch_row($query1);
    echo $result;
```

It doesn't display any value.Could any one help?

Answer (score 0):

you have semicolumn inside of `mysql_query()`, may be by this your query going fail all time

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM listmap where project_id = $_GET['title'];
") or die(mysql_error());
```

change it as

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM listmap where project_id = '".$_GET['title']."'
") or die(mysql_error());
```